# how to add expire date to jwt-simple token

Tags: node.js

```
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {
          // if user is found and password is right create a token
          var expires=moment().add(1,'days').valueOf();
          var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret,{
          exp: expires});
          // return the information including token as JSON
          res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
        } else {
          res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

It prompt error :
/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js:130
    throw new Error('Algorithm not supported');
    ^

Error: Algorithm not supported
    at Object.jwt_encode [as encode] (/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js:130:11)
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/app.js:198:27
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/app/models/user.js:48:9
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:261:17
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:1198:21
    at Immediate.next [as _onImmediate] (/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:1078:21)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not get the token and you should do this :

```
var expires=moment().add(1,'days').valueOf();
          var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret,{
          exp: expires}),app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));
```

Comment: It still prompt same error after add app.get('jwtTokenSecret'), Is any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your secured route should be defined as:

```
router.get('/enums', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res) => { ...
```

where `const passport = require('passport')`.

In order to add expire time to token you must set two parameters (in seconds): `exp` and `nbf` like that:

```
let expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 30
let nbf = Date.now() / 1000

let token = await jwt.encode({nbf: nbf, exp: expires, id: user_id}, jwtSecret).
```

where `const jwt = require('jwt-simple')`